# Best practice for POST request

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, kotlin, backend

I'm making a rest asp.net core with some API that I'll use with an Android app later.

I have some doubt about some of the database operation.

Let's assume that I have in my DB a table Tickets that have columns id, title and author(this is a foreign key which refers the User table (id - name))
Now when the Sndroid app request the list of tickets I made a select and return the id, title and the **name** of the author so I made a class Ticket like this:

```
class Ticket{
private int id{get; set;}
private string Title {get; set;}
private string author {get; set}
}
```

Now assume that the app send a POST request to add a new ticket. What is the best practice?
Send the **title** and the **name** of the author (the client have a copy of author table in local db) or the **title** and the **id** of the author.
So in the first case I have a class for the new Ticket like the one above (without the id) and I have to make a select to get the id of the author and make the insert in the db. In the second case I have a class like that:

```
class Ticket{
private string Title {get; set;}
private int author {get; set}
}
```

and no need to make the select to get the id of the author.
Which one is the best? have two different classes or only one with multiple operations on the db (to get the id of the author).
Now I simplified the example, but imagine that the ticket have more column with foreign keys, what is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand what are your domain objects. From the description I'd say you have at least two: author and ticket.

In this case an author creates a ticket, e.g. on POST authors/{authorId}/tickets. In this case you give a ticket back, i.e. without author id, because author is already known to the client (TicketDTO: id, title. See on DTOs below).

Also what you give back on any particular EP depends on your business requirements, i.e. on the needs of the clients of your API. You have many clients, some of which 3d party? Make your API as generic as possible. You have one client you write youself and you are sure other clients are not coming? Return more info if you need to, epecially if you can save some calls and thus improve performance.

And last but not least, the object that you get from the DB is not the object that you send over REST API (DTO). A DTO may contain info from multiple DB objects. You make your DB based on your backend need, and REST API based on your client needs. And than you map DB objects to DTOs, e.g. with AutoMapper or some other solution.

Comment: Ok but for example when a client send a GET request to get the list of tickets i have to return the id,title and author for each ticket. The DB already exist and i have to make the backend with it. My question is. what is best for POST request? send directly the id of the author or send his name and after that the backend make a select to get his id and make the insert in the DB?

Comment: I'd say with post you send id of the author, and not as post payload, but as part of the url: POST authors/{authorId}/tickets. The server will query the author if needed and insert a ticket into the DB. With get it depends. Does client query all authors and then their tickets? Than author is your aggregate root and you have GET authors and GET authors/{authorId}/tickets. Your client queries list of tickets? Than you have GET tickets and GET tickets/{ticketId}/author or just include author into the ticketDTO: {id, title, author: {id, name...}}.

Comment: It really depends on the needs of your application. REST gives recommendations how to do things, not hard rules. Define your resources first, think about their relations. Which is main resource (aggregate root)? GET them directly, like GET myresources. Which resources make sense only when you've queried the aggregate root already? GET them through main resource, like GET myresources/id/mysubresources. Is it ok for client to make many queries? Make generic fine granular API. CLient is resource constrained? Build bigger DTOs and include more info.

Comment: Yes the client make GET request to get all the tickets. What i don't understand is wich approach is better: when the client send a POST to insert a new ticket in the DB, he send title and his ID or title and his name (and the server will search his ID)